# How can I transition to a state, without hitting the otherwise function or opening other states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that when accessed, it is to redirect to another state. However, I am keep either hitting the otherwise function or getting sent to another state for some reason. Is there a way to transition to a state and kill any other future state openings? This is UI-Router for Angular 1.6

Comment: would be very nice if you put a example

Comment: We could probably help you pretty quickly if you showed us the code for your ui-router and also the code where the redirect is meant to happen